Webhook catched data but does not render due to access permission
The error I got is "You do not have access to order" as seen in the screenshot below.

Does anyone experience this issue? I cannot render the JSON payload to continue with the integration mapping. Zapier Support team had no idea, they guaranteed my paid plan (Legacy) has access to Webhook, but it appears that it does not...
A summary of what I did, but nothing worked

Double checked webhook: everything was configured correctly

Recreated the Zap from scratch: still got the same error message

Firewall or security settings issue: checked and nothing found

Compare Zap settings with different plans:



The settings are identical with a Team plan account, and the Zap in Team plan account returns values as expected.
The settings are identical with a Free plan account, and the Zap in the Free account returns the same error message as what I am having with this Legacy plan.


Use Postman to test: the webhook works fine. Data was sent successfully. Only the payload is not rendered in your Zap configuration view due to the "You do not have access to order" error.


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I wanted to check in to see if you've been able to resolve the issue.
Have you tested the Webhook URL with different data? If that came through successfully, then I suspect that the App/API sending the data to the Webhook doesn't have the correct permissions to send that specific information over to Zapier.
You can use a tool like https://webhook.site/ to generate a Webhook URL and have the same App/API send the data to it, if it shows the same error, then the issue is from the App/API.
Cheers.
DANIEL -Zapier Support

This issue was resolved by changing our plan from the discontinued "Legacy" to a normal "Pro" plan. After that, I was able to set up the Webhook integration using that same data source.
